# Add translucent color between parent and child

Tags: android, xml, view

I want to add color between parent[RelativeLayout] and child[RelativeLayout] like this image below, 
I add black translucent color and make center area to transparent, width and height of transparent area can changeable, I dont know how to create view like this, there is simple way to do this?

[Example Image]

[image]

[Expect Result]

[image]

[Example xml]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear... You just want a layout as shown in the image??

Comment: I updated question above, thank you guys